# Detect if the player is at a specific y level in 1.14

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am in 1.14 and I want to check if the player is at a specific Y value.

I tried `/execute at @a[y=10] run say hi` but for some reason, this will constantly return true no matter what.

I tried `/execute at @a[y=10,distance..2] run say hi` but this will only work if the player's X and Y values match the command blocks.

How do I detect if the player is at a specific Y value/level?

Comment: The key statement in this post is "I am in 1.14". The post you are claiming to be a duplicate of mine is for an older update, as it uses r= as well as the old, execute command.  The post even included someone saying  "It worked for me in 1.7, but I haven't tested this on 1.10 yet."

Comment: @FabianRöling This is definitely not a duplicate of that question.  The question you linked is very outdated.  I am working in 1.14 as I mentioned, and you linked a post from 2017 with the old execute, old r= and someone even says that they haven't even tested it out in 1.10 yet on that post.

Comment: Ok, I retracted the vote. This is definitely a duplicate of something, but I can't find it, so I'll just answer.

Comment: I take it back, I found the original: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/340823/using-execute-command-to-teleport-a-player-under-a-certain-height

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because this question asks for a much higher precision, while the other question asks for the general location.

Comment: @Mr.Bear I 'rejected' your edit, since the OP already asks for a way to detect if the player is at a "specific" position, and making it an 'exact specific' position seems redundant.

Comment: There seems to be a bit of a confusion about that in the comments, so some think that it´s a duplicate of a fairly similar question. I tried to make the difference a little more clear, but understand your decision and I kinda even think that you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a scoreboard objective with this command:

```
/scoreboard objectives add yPos dummy
```

Then you run this command to update the height with very high precision, I recommend using this in a repeating command block:

```
/execute as <target> store result score @s yPos run data get entity @s Pos[1] 1000000
```

And finally to make every target at a very specific y-level say hi you can use this command:

```
/execute as @e[scores={yPos=70000000}] run say hi
```

In this particular case it would be for any entity standing at a y-level of exactly 70.

This solution is multiplayer friendly and works for non-player entities, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
/execute as <player you want to check> at @s if entity @s[y=65,dy=0] run say hi
```

It will say hi if the hitbox of the player is within the block at y=65. the `dy=0` appears to be nessessary to prevent it from always saying hi, the x and z seem to default to the position where the command is executed.

This would probably work, too:

```
/execute at <player you want to check> if entity @p[y=65,dy=0] run say hi
```

Comment: This works, but the accuracy is a bit off.  I noticed that the command works even if the player is not directly at the determined y value.  It is within a range of ~ -1.5 and +0.5.  This can be tested out by using stairs, slowly walking up them, using F3 to check the y value while the command is running.  The "hi" will appear even if not exactly at the desired y value.  Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: The accuracy is not off, the command does apparently not measure quite what you want though. It measures if your hitbox is within a block at a certain hight, the block itself is 1 block high and your hitbox is 1.8 blocks high, or 1.5 while ducking. Crawling reduces it to under 1, but I don't know the exact hight, it looks like about 0.5 blocks though. I will look at it later to see if I can find a more precise solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the next 1 line command to be working. First, execute as all players, then as all players that are at y=10 with dy=0.

```
/execute as @p as @s[y=10,dy=0] run tellraw @s "Test"
```

One thing I found is that y seems to be where any part of the player is.