# Minecraft Execute for y= not Working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to create a command that kills all tnt within a certain distance on a certain y value. The y value, however, seems to specify nothing when I use it. I've looked online and many people have had problems with this, but the solution to these problems was essentially what I've been doing, most often they just had formatting errors. This is what I did:

```
kill @e[type=tnt,y=100,distance=0..100]
```

What this does is completely ignore the y specification, killing all tnt within 100 blocks of the command. On getting rid of the distance tag in case that was the problem, it ran exactly the same as kill @e[type=tnt]

For some reason, the command just completely ignores the y= tag.

Some potentially relevant info:

-This is on Realms

-This is on Java Edition

-There's no other command that kills TNT (I worded this incorrectly, my apologies. I just meant I tested to see if there was some other command block killing all tnt, but there wasn't.)

I don't have any error message, the command just ignores the y value. The question provided as duplicate has a separate problem, however, another duplicate has been marked that has a solution that works for me, despite my hours of research into this.
The duplicate is [this,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352682/detect-if-the-player-is-at-a-specific-y-level-in-1-14) not the one that potentially is listed.

My goal here is for, within 100 blocks of the command, but only on y value 100, for tnt to be killed. So tnt that's on y=101 will not be destroyed, nor will tnt on y=99. All of this would only apply to those y values 100 blocks from the command block.

Comment: "There's no other command that kills TNT" Where does that come from? It's false. Also, what do you actually want to do? Kill all TNT with Y value between 0 and 200?

Comment: @FabianRöling What other command kills TNT? I know that you could teleport it into the void, but what options are there other than that?

Comment: I think you can set `Health` to 0 or `DeathTime` to a positive number, but I'm not sure if that works with non-living things. There are also bugs that delete entities, which you can consistently reproduce. Or you could fill the area below them with air and either just let them fall or give them some negative Y motion. It might also be possible to give them such a high motion that they go through the world. Or you just make them instantly explode by setting their `Fuse` to 0, that also gets rid of them in a way. :)

Comment: I've edited my message to address these concerns. All I want is for tnt at y=100 to be destroyed.

Comment: The duplicate asks how to test for a player at specific coordinates, the y value is a coordinate and you want to test for a specific value of the y value. Make sure to use `@e` instead of `@a` and you should be fine. You need to specify a delta value, which in this case would be `dy=0`.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific on how the question in the duplicate is a different problem? To me they appear to be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command like this:

```
/kill @e[type=minecraft:tnt,x=-100,y=64,z=-100,dx=200,dy=0,dz=200]
```

You need to specify all three coordinates and the delta values for this to work. The coordinates defined with `x y z` are one corner of the specified area, the delta values `dx dy dz` define how many blocks the second corner is away from the first corner.

You wouldn't actually need to specify the distance anymore if you are ok with using a square shape instead of a circle.

You will have to set the coordinates to the values required for your particular case.

Comment: If you need a more precise solution you can check out [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/352682) question.

Comment: Thanks for the more precise solution; while I didnt' need the precision, the command here did not seem to work.
(Dang, I wish I'd found tht comment thread before. I searched for ages looking for a solution)

Comment: You shouldn't mark this answer as accepted if the command here doesn't work. Can you elaborate on why it doesn't work though, at what coordinates is the command block? And you may need the precision, because if you light tnt at y=99, then it will move up a little bit and then the hitbox will be partially inside a block with y=100, so the command would kill it.

Comment: The problem here was exactly the same as my other problem: It just killed all tnt, regardless of coords. My goal has been achieved regardless of the precision problems you mentioned, since the mean reason I didn't want tnt on y99 to be killed was because that just meant it would be likely that things lower would also be killed.

Comment: @Meowl This does work, you do need to use all six parameters though. If you specify `type=tnt`, then nothing other than tnt should be killed anyway. What exact command do you use based on this answer that still doesn't work?